# Spring Boot RandomValuePropertySource nested properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible in some way to "store" the random value generated by `${random.value}` and reference it in other properties as a nested value? I cannot seem to figure how to make this work.

Here is an example of the scenario. I would expect the following test to pass, however, `foo` and `bar` are always resolved to different random values.

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

/**
 * Created by dustin.schultz on 12/14/15.
 */

@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = FooBar.TestApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "foo=${random.value}", "bar=${foo}" })
public class FooBar
{
    @Value("${foo}")
    private String foo;

    @Value("${bar}")
    private String bar;

    @Test
    public void foo()
    {
        assertThat(foo, is(bar));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public static class TestApplication
    {

    }
}
```